# How to save sate of bottom navigation view fragments with use of new android jetpack navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, savestate, android-architecture-navigation

I have a problem with saving the state of fragments which work with bottom navigation view. I am using the new android jetpack navigation library and it is really simple to code bottom navigation with fragments.

I have 3 fragments in the bottom navigation. When I switch, the fragments are recreated.

`OnSaveInstanceState` is never called when I just switch between fragments, so it does not work.
I tried `ViewModel` too, it works but I lose the `recyclerview` position when I switch.

So I just want to simply save the state of fragments with `recyclerviews`. I don't understand why this simple problem is so difficult to solve. Is there any proper way how to achieve this? I have done a lot of research but I have not found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Check this (https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711) to achieve what you want, without android navigation components.

Comment: To achieve it using android navigation components, it seems it is not possible as of now as per the comments in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52716962/9636037